# How to check bool value from an array of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, boolean, nsdictionary

I am looping through an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`, I am then wanting to use one of the values in the `NSDictionary` which is of type `BOOL` for an if statment.. but I am having some trouble doing this.

This is what my `for loop` looks like

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in arrayOfDictionaries)
    {
        NSNumber *boolCheck = [dict objectForKey:@"ISREADY"]; // isReady is the bool value which is either 0 or 1

        if (boolCheck == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) {

//...
   }
}
```

What is happening is it loops through my array but never meets the condition of my if statement even though i am 100% sure there are values of this type in the array... and alot of them for that matter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're attempting to compare two objects by address.  This will tell you if the two objects are the SAME object, but not if they have the same VALUE.  You can compare two NSNumber objects with `isEqualToNumber:`, but extracting and testing the value like Tom suggests is the better approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the NSNumber contains a BOOL, try

```
if ([boolCheck boolValue]) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: so I ran that and it enters the if statement and when i logged boolcheck it only returned the dictionaries where "ISREADY == 1

Comment: @HurkNburkS - I would assume that's what you wanted.

Comment: yup.. lol i thought this was just checking to see if it was a bool i did not know how it was returning only if true. Even after reading the docs i still dont know LOL

Comment: @HurkNburkS - Yeah, it's testing for a boolean TRUE value.  The `[boolCheck boolValue]` function returns the bool value, and the if then tests that bool value.  If you wanted, you could assign the result of the function call to a BOOL and test it in a separate statement.

Comment: @HurkNburkS - Keep in mind that a bool is interchangeable with an int that takes only the values zero or one.  You could just as easily use `[boolCheck intValue]` to get the integer value.

Answer (score 1):

from @Jim Tierney answer here:[JSON to NSDictionary - How to check the boolean type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996356/json-to-nsdictionary-how-to-check-the-boolean-type),
a more elaborate method:

```
    - (BOOL)isBooleanKey:(id)key
{
    if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        if([key isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]
           || [key isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]){
            /* is a bool value if
             <key>somekey</key>
             <true/> or <false/> ie 1 or 0 but not -1, 2, 3 or 1,8
             */
            NSNumber *n = key;
            if (n.intValue) {
                if (n.intValue >= 0 && n.intValue <= 1) return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    // key is not a boolean
    return NO;
}
```

just call like this:

```
if ([self isBooleanKey:[myDict objectForKey:@"some key"]]) {
    // is a bool object for key :-)
}
```

I had problems when the same key could take different classes (NSData, NSString etc.), so boolValue could generate an exception and fail!! 
Above code solves for me

Comment: This solution does not differentiate between values that were inserted as YES (BOOL) from ones inserted as 1 (number).

Comment: Hi @rsc, this code is old and check only for numeric values. To ensure is a real bool value you have to recreate a xml plist using PropertyListSerialization (key is the object) and check if containts "<true/>" or "<false/>". xml rapresentation is just a string, is easy. To do that the first change is to change the method to - (BOOL)isBooleanKey:(NSNumber *)obj  to avoid parsing a complete plist (i.e. just the object for the key you are interested in).