# JSON to NSDictionary - How to check the boolean type

Tags: objective-c

I get JSON from site using this code:

```
+(NSDictionary *)parseJSONFromURLString:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *jsonAsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                         error:nil];
    NSData *json = [jsonAsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:nil];
}
```

When I am calling this method and debugging:

```
NSDictionary *response = [APIUtils parseJSONFromURLString:[queryBuilder questionsFromTime:time WithPageSize:100 WithPage:1]];
```

I can look at jsonAsString variable in the parseJSONFromURLString (NSString) method I can see the element "has_more" with value true:

```
  ..., "has_more":true, ....
```

But If I look at responseVariable (NSDictionary) I see next picture:

[image]

The value have __NSCFBoolean type and 0X7fff79d377f0 value.

How can I convert this type to BOOL and check it as true or false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNumber class has the method:
    - (BOOL)boolValue

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-boolValue

Answer (score 2):

Using this if statement should detect if the value for that key is true or false.

```
if([[response objectForKey:@"has_more"] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]]){

     //hits here if this value is true

}else{

     //and here if it's not.
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Why not just : `if([response[@"has_more"] boolValue]){}` ?

Comment: Thanks!! boolvalue is buggie if your key is not actually a boolean key (in the case the same  key can be saved as NSString, NSData ecc... returning an exception). So if([[response objectForKey:@"has_more"] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] || [[response objectForKey:@"has_more"] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]){ can tell you if the key is a boolean...really

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a `NSNumber`, you can get its `boolValue`.

Comment: A bit more description woudl have been useful. At least place the change in the questioners code.